# Preventing forge HttpRequests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, httphandler, httprequest

I've been searching throughout the day to find a way to figure this out, but without sucess and I thought that maybe someone here could help ? 
I am trying to use a secrete password in my .Js file but I can't write it directly in the file because everyone could see it when accessing the source code. e.g I need to send this password using ajax to another page to make sure that the HttpRequest is from my website not from another forge httprequest . 
 Is that possible because I've tried everything else like Authentication Forms but that didn't help.
I'm using asp.net and HttpHandler as the page that returns data .

Comment: Most of the major platforms include some sort of native antiforgery token. It would help if we knew what web framework you're using.

Comment: ASP.NET 3.5 is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is generate a key that is valid up to a set time using PHP like so:

```
$password = "some random string";
$key = md5($password . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . "|" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
```

This way you know when the key was generated, and if it's been tampered with because:

```
function check($key) {
    list($hash, $timestamp) = explode("|", $key, 2);
    if ($hash !== md5($password . $key)) {
        throw new Exception("Naughty!");
    }
    if ($timestamp < $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] < 60*60) {
        throw new Exception("too old");
    }
}
```

The down side is that people who don't refresh the page very often (in my example this is 1 hour) their key will expire.

Another issue is that your 'attacker' could technically first scrape a page to get a new key and use that, and scrape again when it expires and so on.

This solution works very good for protecting against hotlinking.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's done [in MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx). Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the same security goodness has made it to WebForms (at least as far as I can tell).